# flutter: Edit a ListView Item

Tags: flutter, dart, listview, edit

i want to edit a listview item when i click on it. I managed (with inkwell) that when I click on a listview item, the bottomsheet opens again where I also create new listview items, but I just can't edit it. I've tried everything I know (I don't know much I'm a beginner). here my codes.

**--main.dart--**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_localizations/flutter_localizations.dart';

import '/model/transaction.dart';
import '/widget/chart.dart';
import '/widget/new_transaction.dart';
import '/widget/transactoin_list.dart';

void main() {
  // WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  // SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations(
  //   [
  //     DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
  //     DeviceOrientation.portraitDown,
  //   ],
  // );
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      localizationsDelegates: const [
        GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
        GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
        GlobalCupertinoLocalizations.delegate,
      ],
      supportedLocales: const [
        Locale("de"),
        Locale("en"),
      ],
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: "URLI",
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.lightGreen,
        fontFamily: "JosefinSans",
        textTheme: ThemeData()
            .textTheme
            .copyWith(
              headline4: const TextStyle(
                fontFamily: "Tochter",
                fontSize: 21,
              ),
              headline5: const TextStyle(
                fontFamily: "Bombing",
                fontSize: 27,
                letterSpacing: 3,
              ),
              headline6: const TextStyle(
                fontSize: 21,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w900,
              ),
            )
            .apply(
              bodyColor: Colors.orangeAccent,
              displayColor: Colors.orangeAccent.withOpacity(0.5),
            ),
        elevatedButtonTheme: ElevatedButtonThemeData(
          style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
            onPrimary: Colors.white,
            primary: Theme.of(context).appBarTheme.backgroundColor,
            textStyle: const TextStyle(
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
            ),
          ),
        ),
        appBarTheme: const AppBarTheme(
          titleTextStyle: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 60,
            fontFamily: "Tochter",
          ),
        ),
      ),
      home: const AusgabenRechner(),
    );
  }
}

class AusgabenRechner extends StatefulWidget {
  const AusgabenRechner({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<AusgabenRechner> createState() => _AusgabenRechnerState();
}

class _AusgabenRechnerState extends State<AusgabenRechner> {
  void _submitAddNewTransaction(BuildContext ctx) {
    showModalBottomSheet(
      context: ctx,
      builder: (_) {
        return GestureDetector(
          onTap: () {},
          child: NewTransaction(addNewTx: _addNewTransaction),
          behavior: HitTestBehavior.opaque,
        );
      },
    );
  }

  bool _showChart = false;

  final List<Transaction> _userTransactions = [
    // Transaction(
    //   id: "tx1",
    //   tittel: "Schuhe",
    //   preis: 99.99,
    //   datum: DateTime.now(),
    // ),
    // Transaction(
    //   id: "tx2",
    //   tittel: "Jacke",
    //   preis: 39.99,
    //   datum: DateTime.now(),
    // ),
  ];

  List<Transaction> get _recentTransactions {
    return _userTransactions
        .where(
          (tx) => tx.datum.isAfter(
            DateTime.now().subtract(
              const Duration(days: 7),
            ),
          ),
        )
        .toList();
  }

  void _addNewTransaction(
    String txTittel,
    double txPreis,
    DateTime choosenDate,
  ) {
    final newTx = Transaction(
      id: DateTime.now().toString(),
      tittel: txTittel,
      preis: txPreis,
      datum: choosenDate,
    );

    setState(() {
      _userTransactions.add(newTx);
    });
  }

  void _deletedTransaction(String id) {
    setState(() {
      _userTransactions.removeWhere((tdddx) => tdddx.id == id);
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final mediaQuery = MediaQuery.of(context);
    final isInLandscape = mediaQuery.orientation == Orientation.landscape;

    final appBar = AppBar(
      centerTitle: true,
      toolbarHeight: 99,
      actions: [
        IconButton(
          onPressed: () => _submitAddNewTransaction(context),
          icon: const Icon(
            Icons.add,
            color: Colors.white,
          ),
        ),
      ],
      title: const Text(
        "Ausgaben",
      ),
    );

    final txListWidget = SizedBox(
      height: (mediaQuery.size.height -
              appBar.preferredSize.height -
              mediaQuery.padding.top) *
          0.45,
      child: TransactionList(
        transaction: _userTransactions,
        delettx: _deletedTransaction,
        showNewTransaction: _submitAddNewTransaction,
      ),
    );

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: appBar,
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            if (isInLandscape)
              SizedBox(
                height: (mediaQuery.size.height -
                        appBar.preferredSize.height -
                        mediaQuery.padding.top) *
                    0.2,
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    Text(
                      "Chart anzeigen",
                      style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline5,
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(width: 9),
                    Switch.adaptive(
                      inactiveTrackColor:
                          Theme.of(context).primaryColor.withOpacity(0.3),
                      activeColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                      value: _showChart,
                      onChanged: (val) {
                        setState(() {
                          _showChart = val;
                        });
                      },
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            if (!isInLandscape)
              SizedBox(
                height: (mediaQuery.size.height -
                        appBar.preferredSize.height -
                        mediaQuery.padding.top) *
                    0.24,
                child: Chart(
                  recentTransactions: _recentTransactions,
                ),
              ),
            if (!isInLandscape)
              SizedBox(
                  height: (mediaQuery.size.height -
                          appBar.preferredSize.height -
                          mediaQuery.padding.top) *
                      0.65,
                  child: txListWidget),
            if (isInLandscape)
              _showChart
                  ? SizedBox(
                      height: (mediaQuery.size.height -
                              appBar.preferredSize.height -
                              mediaQuery.padding.top) *
                          0.51,
                      child: Chart(
                        recentTransactions: _recentTransactions,
                      ),
                    )
                  : SizedBox(
                      height: (mediaQuery.size.height -
                              appBar.preferredSize.height -
                              mediaQuery.padding.top) *
                          0.81,
                      child: txListWidget)
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerDocked,
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        child: const Icon(
          Icons.add,
          color: Colors.white,
        ),
        onPressed: () => _submitAddNewTransaction(context),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**--transaction_list.dart--**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

import '/model/transaction.dart';

class TransactionList extends StatefulWidget {
  const TransactionList({
    Key? key,
    required this.transaction,
    required this.delettx,
    required this.showNewTransaction,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final List<Transaction> transaction;
  final Function delettx;
  final Function showNewTransaction;

  @override
  State<TransactionList> createState() => _TransactionListState();
}

class _TransactionListState extends State<TransactionList> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return widget.transaction.isEmpty
        ? LayoutBuilder(
            builder: (ctx, contrains) {
              return Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  Text(
                    "Keine Daten vorhanden!",
                    style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline6,
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(
                    height: 30,
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: contrains.maxHeight * 0.45,
                    child: Image.asset(
                      "assets/images/schlafen.png",
                      fit: BoxFit.cover,
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              );
            },
          )
        : Align(
            alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
            child: ListView.builder(
              shrinkWrap: true,
              reverse: true,
              itemCount: widget.transaction.length,
              itemBuilder: (ctx, index) {
                return InkWell(
                  onLongPress: () => widget.showNewTransaction(ctx),
                  child: Card(
                    elevation: 5,
                    child: ListTile(
                      leading: CircleAvatar(
                        radius: 33,
                        child: Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(9.0),
                          child: FittedBox(
                            child: Row(
                              children: [
                                Text(
                                  widget.transaction[index].preis
                                      .toStringAsFixed(2),
                                  style: const TextStyle(
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                    fontSize: 24,
                                  ),
                                ),
                                const Text(
                                  "€",
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 21,
                                  ),
                                )
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      title: Text(
                        widget.transaction[index].tittel,
                        style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline6,
                      ),
                      subtitle: Text(
                        DateFormat.yMMMMd("de")
                            .format(widget.transaction[index].datum),
                        style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
                      ),
                      trailing: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width > 460
                          ? TextButton.icon(
                              onPressed: () =>
                                  widget.delettx(widget.transaction[index].id),
                              icon: const Icon(
                                Icons.delete_outline,
                              ),
                              label: const Text("Löschen"),
                              style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                                primary: Colors.red,
                              ),
                            )
                          : IconButton(
                              onPressed: () =>
                                  widget.delettx(widget.transaction[index].id),
                              icon: const Icon(
                                Icons.delete_outline,
                                color: Colors.red,
                              ),
                            ),
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              },
            ),
          );
  }
}
```

**--new_transaction.dart--**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

class NewTransaction extends StatefulWidget {
  const NewTransaction({Key? key, required this.addNewTx}) : super(key: key);

  final Function addNewTx;

  @override
  State<NewTransaction> createState() => _NewTransactionState();
}

class _NewTransactionState extends State<NewTransaction> {
  final _tittelcontroller = TextEditingController();

  final _preiscontroller = TextEditingController();

  DateTime? _selectedDate;

  void _submitData() {
    final enteredTittel = _tittelcontroller.text;
    final enteredPreis = double.parse(_preiscontroller.text);

    if (_preiscontroller.text.isEmpty) {
      return;
    }
    if (enteredTittel.isEmpty || enteredPreis <= 0 || _selectedDate == null) {
      return;
    }
    widget.addNewTx(
      _tittelcontroller.text,
      double.parse(_preiscontroller.text),
      _selectedDate,
    );
    Navigator.of(context).pop();
  }

  void _presentDatePicker() {
    showDatePicker(
      context: context,
      initialDate: DateTime.now(),
      firstDate: DateTime(2022),
      lastDate: DateTime.now(),
    ).then((pickedDate) {
      if (pickedDate == null) {
        return;
      }
      setState(() {
        _selectedDate = pickedDate;
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      bottom: false,
      child: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Container(
          //height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.5,
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(
            top: 10,
            left: 18,
            right: 18,
            bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom + 10,
          ),
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
            children: [
              TextButton(
                onPressed: _submitData,
                child: Text(
                  "hinzufügen",
                  style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headlineSmall,
                ),
              ),
              TextField(
                controller: _tittelcontroller,
                onSubmitted: (_) => _submitData(),
                decoration: const InputDecoration(
                  label: Text("Tittel"),
                ),
              ),
              TextField(
                controller: _preiscontroller,
                keyboardType:
                    const TextInputType.numberWithOptions(decimal: true),
                onSubmitted: (_) => _submitData(),
                decoration: const InputDecoration(
                  label: Text("Preis"),
                ),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 66),
                child: Center(
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      Text(
                        _selectedDate == null
                            ? "Kein Datum ausgewählt"
                            : DateFormat.yMMMMEEEEd("de")
                                .format(_selectedDate!),
                        style: const TextStyle(
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          fontSize: 18,
                        ),
                      ),
                      const SizedBox(
                        height: 21,
                      ),
                      ElevatedButton(
                        style: Theme.of(context).elevatedButtonTheme.style,
                        onPressed: _presentDatePicker,
                        child: const Text("Datum wählen"),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score -2):

EN: Here is an excample code, how i would solve this, when i understood the problem. The passing of the variables to the new Class is a bit differnent then in your Code but it works the same.

DE: So hier ist jetzt ein Beispielcode, wie ich es lösen würde, wenn ich das Problem richtig verstanden habe, dabei werden die Variabeln etwas anders als bei dir in die neue Klasse übergeben, funktioniert aber gleich

```
class testListview extends StatefulWidget {
 var transaction;
 var delettx;
 var showNewTransaction;
 //Passing the data to new Class
 testListview(this.transaction, this.delettx, 
 this.showNewTransaction);

 @override
 State<testListview> createState() => _testListviewState();
}

class _testListviewState extends State<testListview> {

 var transaction;
 var delettx;
 var showNewTransaction;

 //Pass the data into the State of the new Class
 _testListviewState(this.transaction, this.delettx, 
 this.showNewTransaction);


 var transaction_2;

 //The init state will be called in the first initialization of 
 //the Class
 
 @override
 void initState() {
  //Pass your transactions to a new variable
  setState(() {
    transaction_2 = transaction;
  });
  super.initState();
} 


@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return ListView.builder(itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, 
  index){
  return TextButton(onPressed: (){
    //Change the data with onPressed
    setState(() {
      transaction_2["preis"] = "500";
    });
  }, child: Text(transaction_2["preis"]));
});}}
```

Comment: danke für deine Antwort aber kannst du mir das für dumme erklären :)

Comment: Habe die antwort mit einem Code beispiel verändert

Comment: [Please translate this into English](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/297680/354577)

Comment: Changed it do englisch

Comment: danke für deine Mühe aber ich glaub ich konnte mich nicht richtig verständlich machen. Ich will wenn ich auf ein item drauf klicke (siehe Foto: i want to edit this) das mein buttomsheet erscheint (buttomsheet habe ich erstellt weil ich für neue items in der Liste ein Input brauche) und würde dann die neuen eingegebenen Inputs ersetzten. Also dumm gesagt ich will auf "i want to edit this" klicken und es bearbeiten und dann soll da anstatt i want... bearbeitet stehen. ich hoffe du kannst nicht verstehen.